# python: Why diff processes return same epoll object when calling select.epoll()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, epoll

**My goal**: start N sub-processes, each deal with different socket sets.
-- This means different epoll objects are needed.
**Porblem**: When i call select.epoll() in sub-processes, it returns the same object.
Here's a simple example below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Lock
import time,select,os

class A(Process):
    def run(self):
        fd = select.epoll()
        print 'A.pid=',os.getpid(),'poll_fd:', fd, fd.fileno()
        while 1:
            poll_list = fd.poll(timeout=3600)
            for fd,events in poll_list:
                pass

class B(Process):
    def run(self):
        fd = select.epoll()
        print 'B.pid=',os.getpid(),'poll_fd:', fd, fd.fileno()
        while 1:
            poll_list = fd.poll(timeout=3600)
            for fd,events in poll_list:
                pass

A().start()
B().start()
```

Why did this happen?
What should i do to fix it?
Any help will be appreciated.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this are different processes, the epoll resources are also different. Each process has it's own set of file numbers. They lowest free file number is selected for a new resource. That's why both processes uses the same file number. No fix needed.

Comment: according to my test, they are diff instances. the program seems to work fine. thanks.